# Scroll to the last two rows of table

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

when the table has more records than the screen let you see, and the user scroll to the bottom for the last records in the table, the last two rows are not accessible (just in iOS7, in iOS8 everything is fine). Once the user take the finger from screen, the table goes up, and the last two rows are hidden.

This is one of the method used for tableView but i dont know if this come from here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *  cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

if (selectionCategMsg == 0)
{
    if ([self.tableauMsgReceived count] < 1) {
        cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"noMessagesYet", nil); //@"No messages yet !";
    }

    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.tableauMsgReceived objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    }
}

else
{
    if ([self.tableauMsgSent count] < 1) {
        cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"noReplyYet", nil);
    }

    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.tableauMsgSent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]].UTF8String];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    }
}

[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

return cell;
}
```

Can someone give an advice ? Thank you.

THIS IS THE SOLUTION THAT I FOUND:

```
// -> SET TABLE FRAME
CGFloat sideMargin = 0;
CGFloat originX = sideMargin;

CGFloat topBottomMargin = 100;
CGFloat originY = topBottomMargin;

// Width based on view size
CGFloat sizeWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width);

// Height based on view size
CGFloat sizeHeight = (self.view.bounds.size.height - topBottomMargin);

self.myTableView.frame = CGRectMake(originX, originY, sizeWidth, sizeHeight);
// <- END SET tableView frame
```

Comment: The tableView has the wrong bounds and goes out of the screen... the view has the wrong frame. show the code where you create the table and/or the xib

Comment: and remove all that unrelated code

Answer (score 0):

UITableView has the method `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`. That method lets you scroll the table view so a given indexPath is visible. Is that what you're looking for?

EDIT:

@Daij-Djan's post is a good theory on what's wrong. If your table view goes off the screen then it will position the last couple of cells inside it's view,  but that view won't be visible. You're going to need to do some debugging to figure out what's wrong. You might try setting the table view's layer's borderWidth to a non-zero value so you can see the bounds of the table view.

In your viewDidLoad, add code like this:

```
myTableView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
myTableView.layer.borderColor= [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
```

(Where you'd replace "myTableView" with the name of your table view instance variable or property.)

You'll have to import QuartzCore.h in order for the code above to compile:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: Post your code then. I've used that method and it works fine.

Comment: @Developer3000 ?????? I so vote to close this ... you said you tried something of which you don't even know where it is :D

Comment: when i wrote "i already tried it" that's means exactly that. Obviously your reply will not help nobody. Try to keep for yourself such comments unless you have an answer to the question posted.

Comment: @Duncan Thanks, i used your code and i can see the borders left, right and top, but not the bottom

Comment: for people interested I modified my question adding the solution that I found. @Duncan : thanks for reply me